# Data Copy using Azure Data Factory and get a event notification containing changed record id's

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My Source, Target database is Azure DB for MYSQL. For simplicity let's Assume there is only 1 table in source and target database.

We are using Azure Data Factory Copy Activity to move data from Source to Target.
Source table contains latest records, so we copy them to target table as well. So, in fact its Update of records in Target Table from Source Table.

We want some Event Notification from Azure Data Factory about what records actually changed. Can Azure Data Factory generate some event Notification for say Azure EventGrid? Azure EventBus? etc?

Comment: For any custom alerts that are not in the metrics tab, use Log Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in 2 different ways, and I'll offer a 3rd possible suggestion.

1. Use a staging table as a sink, then with a script activity use a SQL query to identify the new records. You could then insert those into the target table, and into some other table to track the new things. Or, you could have an insert timestamp in the sink table and that will show what is new each time.
2. Enable Change Tracking on the source database, and build queries using that.
3. Use ADF CDC. I haven't done this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-change-data-capture